# ResCarta in Jelastic?

Tags: tomcat, jelastic

I'm trying to get the Tomcat app [ResCarta](https://rescarta.org/index.php/sw/rescarta-web) into my Reclaim Cloud account (Jelastic). I can get the ResCarta website to work on my computer via a local port, but I can't get it to deploy onto Jelastic. I've tried deploying the download package .zip folder, and created a war file to deploy, but each just results in a 404 error. Is there a way to get ResCarta to work on this?

Edit: I can get the base page of ResCarta to appear if I deploy it to Auto-Scalable GlassFish Cluster, but if I try to navigate to any other page, it results in an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /jsp/RcWebBrowse.jsp(420,397) PWC6317: The attributes for a standard action or an uninterpreted tag cannot be deferred expressions
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.1.0 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.1.0
```

Comment: Please post the corresponding log excerpt: https://docs.jelastic.com/view-log-files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create container with Java 9.0.37 + OpenJDK-15.ea-b33 (for example)
2. Deploy the archive rc-web-7.0.3.zip to the created environment with default options
3. Move all contents of folder "/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/ResCarta-Web/*" to "/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/" [image: Move all contents]
4. Check your environment link http://env-xxxxxxx.xx.reclaim.cloud/ again.[image: check web link of your environment]